# Center of circle when three points in $3$-space are given

Tags: calculus

How do we find center of a circle passing through three points:

$ A(x_1,y_2,z_3),B(x_1,y_2,z_3),C(x_1,y_2,z_3) $?

Can we minimize $ (d_{OA}+...+... )    $ with  condition $ d_{OA}=...=... ,$

or is the volume of tetrahedron $ OABC =0$ adequate to find it with the latter distance equalities ?

Is the result/formula known? Thanks for the indications.

Comment: Do you know off hand what the values of $A, B$, and $C$ are? or do you want a formula in general terms?

Comment: @Narasimham: I'd consider perpendicular bisector planes of $AB,\,BC,\,CA$ intersection (it's a line) and intersection of this line with plane $ABC$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define

$$\begin{cases}
a &= |\vec{B}-\vec{C}|,\\
b &= |\vec{C}-\vec{A}|,\\
c &= |\vec{A}-\vec{B}|
\end{cases}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\begin{cases}
\alpha &= a^2(b^2+c^2-a^2)\\
\beta  &= b^2(c^2+a^2-b^2)\\
\gamma &= c^2(a^2+b^2-c^2)
\end{cases}$$
The center you want is given by the formula

$$\vec{X}_{circum} = \frac{\alpha \vec{A} + \beta \vec{B} + \gamma\vec{C}}{\alpha + \beta + \gamma}$$

What we have done is lifting the formula for [circumcenter in barycentric coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Examples) from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$. The $X_{circum}$ so constructed is the 
circumcenter of the triangle $\triangle ABC$ in the plane containing it.

Comment: Thanks. The barycentric coordinates link came in and vanished!

Comment: @Narasimham strange, I don't have any trouble with the link. anyone else has problem with that?

Comment: it has now reappeared.Please ignore it.