# Parameterize a circle (given x, y, z cooridnates on its circumference) in 3D

Tags: matrices, geometry, circles, parametrization

I have a circle defined by a set of $x, y$ and $z$ coordinates. The circle exists across $3$ planes. I would know how to parameterize a $2$-d circle (say in just the $x$-$y$ plane) into polar coordinates, but not in $3$-d. **How do I do this?** I visualized the set of $x, y$ and $z$ coordinates in Paraview so I could see the orientation of the circle; this can be seen below.

I need to paramterize this circle because I need to define the $x, y$ and $z$
 points I was given as angles around the circumference of that circle.

[image]

(Note the circle of interest is the translucent white object in the centre of the cube domain)

Comment: How is the circle given exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

[Find from your data the center](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3294317/255730) $O$ of the circle and then two points $A$, $B$ on the circle such that $OA\perp OB$. The parametric equation of the circle is then:
$$
(x,y,z)=O+(A-O)\cos\phi+(B-O)\sin\phi.
$$
Inserting here the coordinates of a given point of the circle you can solve for $\cos\phi$ and $\sin\phi$. Of course point $A$ corresponds to $\phi=0$.